# re.split giving dempty string when trying to split at "."

Tags: python, python-re

I want to extract domain name from a url.
I want to split the string of url at "http://" and ".".
But spliting at "." is not working where as spliting at ".com" is .
Can you explain why the second set of code gives empty string ?

```
#spliting at "http://" and ".com"
a="http://github.com/carbonfive/raygun"
import re
a=re.split("http://",a)[1]
a=re.split(".com",a)[0]
a
'github'

#spliting at "http://" and "."
a="http://github.com/carbonfive/raygun"
import re
a=re.split("http://",a)[1]
a=re.split(".",a)[0]
a
''
```

Comment: What's wrong with ```a.split("http://")[1].split('.')[0]``` ?

Answer (score 3):

In Regular Expressions the `.` is a symbol that match anything.  To escape it you can do `\.` and your solution will work. However this isn't a very good use of regex.  Instead i suggest this:

```
a="http://github.com/carbonfive/raygun"
a=re.match("http://(.*)\..*",a).groups()[0]
```

which yields "github".